# To schedule task

Tags: scheduled-tasks

Iam using Windows7..And i want to schedule task for multiple timings.Means the schedule task should send mail for 2times a day .Around 9am and 3pm.I have searched a lot but cant find ..Please Some one out there help me out

Thanks for any response

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Look at

```
Start Menu -> All Programs -> Accessories -> System Tools -> Task Scheduler
```